# Loop through enums without duplication in Java

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to loop through any enum without duplicating the loops?

Say I have two enums.

```
public enum Type {

    X("x type"),
    Y("y type"),
    Z("z type"),

    private String text;

    private Type(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}

public enum Size {

    SMALL("tiny"),
    MED("mid"), ...

    private String text;

    private Size(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I can loop through individual enums like this:

```
for (Type type : Type.values()) {
    ... do something with type.name(), type.toString()
}

for (Size s : Size.values()) {
    ... do "the same" something with s.name(), S.toString()
}
```

Is it possible to loop through them without duplicating the code for each enum type? What is the best approach to avoid the entire loop duplication in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use generics, i.e. like this:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>>  void loopEnum( Class<E> enumClass ) {
  for( E e : enumClass.getEnumConstants() ) {
    System.out.println( e.toString() );
  }
}
```

So basically you're telling the method that it should accept any enum class, i.e. one that extends `Enum<E>` which implicitly is the case for enums.

Comment: Wonderful. Power of generics :)

Comment: ... and reflection :) - but as always "with great power comes great responsibility"

Comment: @Thomas Are you Thomas Wayne?? :P

Comment: @KumarAbhinav posting from the otherworld ;)